# Решение Судоку рекурсией

Tags: python, алгоритм

Необходимо считать судоку из файла,записать в матрицу и решить рекурсией.Как верно составить рекурсию?В текущей версии работает неверно

```
def read_sudoku(filename):
     """ Прочитать Судоку из указанного файла """
     digits = [c for c in open(filename).read() if c in '123456789.']
     grid = group(digits, 9)
     return grid


def display(values):
"""Вывод Судоку """
    width = 2
    line = '+'.join(['-' * (width * 3)] * 3)
    for row in range(9):
        print(''.join(values[row][col].center(width) + ('|' if str(col) in    '25' else '') for col in range(9)))
        if str(row) in '25':
             print(line)
    print()


 def group(values, n):

    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    j = 0
    for i in values:
        if j < n:
            list2.append(i)
            j += 1
        if j == n:
            j = 0
            list1.append(list2)
            list2 = []
    return list1


def get_row(values, pos):

    row, col = pos
    i = 0
    list = []
    for j in values:
        if i == row:
            list = j
        i += 1
    return list


def get_col(values, pos):

    row, col = pos
    list = []
    for j in values:
        for i in range(len(j)):
            if i == col:
                list.append(j[i])
    return list


def get_block(values, pos):
""" Возвращает все значения из квадрата, в который попадает позиция pos """
    row, col = pos
    i = 0
    j = 0
    list = []
    borderRow1 = 0
    borderRow2 = 0
    borderCol1 = 0
    borderCol2 = 0
    if (row <= 2) and (row >= 0):
        borderRow1 = 0
        borderRow2 = 2
    elif (row <= 5) and (row >= 3):
        borderRow1 = 3
        borderRow2 = 5
    else:
        borderRow1 = 6
        borderRow2 = 8

    if (col <= 2) and (col >= 0):
         borderCol1 = 0
         borderCol2 = 2
    elif (col <= 5) and (col >= 3):
        borderCol1 = 3
        borderCol2 = 5
    else:
        borderCol1 = 6
        borderCol2 = 8


    while i <= 8:

        while j <= 8:

            if (i >= borderRow1) and (i <= borderRow2) and (j >= borderCol1) and (j <= borderCol2):


                list.append(values[i][j])
            j += 1
        j = 0
        i += 1
    return list


def find_empty_positions(grid):

    row = 0
    col = 0
    t = True
    for i in grid:
        if t:
            for y in i:
                if y == '.':
                    t = False
                    break
                col += 1
            if t:
                col = 0
                row += 1
        else:
            break
    if t:
        return None
    else:
        return (row, col)


def find_possible_values(grid, pos):
""" Вернуть все возможные значения для указанной позиции """
    answer = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    list1 = get_row(grid, pos)

    for i in list1:
        for j in answer:
            if i == j:
                answer.remove(j)

    list2 = get_col(grid, pos)

    for i in list2:
        for j in answer:
            if i == j:
                answer.remove(j)
    list3 = get_block(grid, pos)

    for i in list3:
        for j in answer:
            if i == j:
                answer.remove(j)
    return answer


def solve(grid):
""" Решение пазла, заданного в grid """
""" Как решать Судоку?
    1. Найти свободную позицию
    2. Найти все возможные значения, которые могут находиться на этой позиции
    3. Для каждого возможного значения:
        3.1. Поместить это значение на эту позицию
        3.2. Продолжить решать оставшуюся часть пазла
"""


    def answer(values):
        print('answer')
        setka = []
        t = find_empty_positions(values)

        print(t)

        if t != None:
            row, col = t
            e = find_possible_values(values, t)
            print('Possible values')
            print(e)

            setka = values
            if len(e) > 0:
                for i in e:
                    setka[row][col] = i

                    display(setka)

                    if check_solution(setka):
                        return setka
                    else:
                        answer(setka)


    true_answer = answer(grid)



def check_solution(solution):
""" Если решение solution верно, то вернуть True, в противном случае False """
    list1 = [0]*9
    t = True
    for i in solution:
        if t:
            for j in i:
                if j == '.' :
                    t = False
                    break
                else:
                    list1[int(j) - 1] += 1
                    if list1[int(j)-1] > 9:
                        t = False
                        break
        else:
            break
    if t:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for fname in ['puzzle1.txt', 'puzzle2.txt', 'puzzle3.txt']:
        grid = read_sudoku(fname)
        display(grid)
        solution = solve(grid)
        display(solution)
        print()
```

Comment: А вы представляете сколько это работать будет? И проверьте что после выхода из рекурсии состояние корректно возвращается. Я это не вижу, но может просто не заметил.

Comment: Когда я писал решалку Судоку :), то я сначала находил все клетки, в которых может быть только одна цифра, и только потом занимался ветвями с отсечениями (хотя в принципе, есть еще несколько неплохих вариантов до того, как приступать к ветвлению). Но начинать с самого начала рекурсию - пожалуй, перебор...

Comment: @Harry у меня был вопрос по поводу сетки, и написал в итоге я генератор, со сложностями, а потом прикрутил решалку, кстати с таким же принципом как и Вы описали, довольно быстро решал он легкий и средний уровни!

Comment: Судоку таки интереснее решать аналитически, и выводить список применённых алгоритмов. Иначе смысл в такой решалке? "Вы, чего, и конфеты за меня есть будете?" (с)

Comment: Вот [одно из рекурсивных решений](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html)